# Right hand side position of substring MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, position, substring, locate

I need to blank SSN's from an audit/log table and we can't alter the application.

The application produces an audit/log into table 'redcap_log_event', column 'sql_log'. This column is simply a long string of SQL used by the application when each command was performed within the app.

This is an example of the sql_log column when you copy and paste it out, the carriage returns are in the string of SQL from the column. The inserts end up in the sql_log column from the application -

```
INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'study_id', '123456789', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'cmr_date', '2015-09-02', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'first_name', 'bnm', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'last_name', 'asdfggh', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'dob', '2015-09-02', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'age_at_cmr', '21', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'social_security_number', '987582154', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'sex', '1', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'ethnicity', '1', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'demographics_abef_complete', '2', NULL);
 INSERT INTO redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value, instance) VALUES (6, 21, 'Ashby, zbn', 'participant_id', 'asdfggh, zbn', NULL)
```

I am wanting to eventually blank out the 9 digit SSN value from within the above data via a trigger on the table but for now i'm struggling to get a substring, regex, locate to work how i need it to - The position of text 'social_security_number' within column sql_log will always be different because of the firstname and lastname inserts before it, so i need to somehow find a varying position on the right side of 'social_security_number'

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: It seems that MySQL does not yet support a replace function with regex. You may have to try using a user defined function (UDF) from an external library: [MySQL UDF with Regex](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)

Comment: If it was possible to use regex it could be accomplished with this one: ``/(?<=social_security_number', )('\d{9}')/Ug`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD9wN9/2))

Comment: Thanks for that. Regexp is available in MySQL but i'm not sure how i'd implemented that sql into a statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the downvotes, friendly community i see. Anyway, this is what i finished with:-

```
USE `ctsiredcap`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `SsnBlankOutInsert`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `ctsiredcap`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SsnBlankOutInsert` ()
BEGIN
UPDATE redcap_log_event 
SET 
    sql_log = CONCAT(SUBSTR(sql_log,
                1,
                LOCATE('social_security_number', sql_log) + 25),
            '*********',
            SUBSTR(sql_log,
                LOCATE('social_security_number', sql_log) + 35)),
    data_values = CONCAT(SUBSTR(data_values,
                1,
                LOCATE('social_security_number', data_values) + 25),
            '*********',
            SUBSTR(data_values,
                LOCATE('social_security_number', data_values) + 35))
WHERE
    ts > REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE,
                '-',
                ''),
            ':',
            ''),
        ' ',
        '')
        AND LOCATE('social_security_number', sql_log) > 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Not pretty by any means but it seems to be doing the job

Thanks,
Allan